# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected server error.' using EdgeOptions

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run a test using the W3C spec of Selenium WebDriver with C#.
This is my code which I believe is correct based on reading the W3C docs [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/).

```
    [Test]
    public void SimpleSelenium4Example()
    {

        //TODO please supply your Sauce Labs user name in an environment variable
        var sauceUserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_USERNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        //TODO please supply your own Sauce Labs access Key in an environment variable
        var sauceAccessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

        var options = new EdgeOptions()
        {
            BrowserVersion = "latest",
            PlatformName = "Windows 10"
        };

        var sauceOptions = new JObject
        {
            ["username"] = sauceUserName,
            ["accessKey"] = sauceAccessKey,
            ["name"] = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name
        };
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions.ToString());

        Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        Assert.Pass();
    }
```

I get this error **OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'Unexpected server error.'** when instantiating the RemoteWebDriver.

Not sure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET bindings serialize the objects appropriately; there's no need to attempt to use the Json.NET API at all (as your use of `JObject` implies you are), and serializing the JSON object (using `ToString()`) before transmission over the wire is likely to be unsuccessful.

```
[Test]
public void SimpleSelenium4Example()
{
    //TODO please supply your Sauce Labs user name in an environment variable
    var sauceUserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_USERNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
    //TODO please supply your own Sauce Labs access Key in an environment variable
    var sauceAccessKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

    var options = new EdgeOptions()
    {
        BrowserVersion = "latest",
        PlatformName = "Windows 10"
    };

    var sauceOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    sauceOptions["username"] = sauceUserName;
    sauceOptions["accessKey"] = sauceAccessKey;
    sauceOptions["name"] = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;

    options.AddAdditionalCapability("sauce:options", sauceOptions);

    Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
    Assert.Pass();
}
```